# (Definition) Why is Z not a pivotal quantity while estimating the mean of a normal distribution when variance is unknown?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, pivot

The definition of a *pivotal quantity* as given in Wikipedia is:

> In statistics, a pivotal quantity or pivot is a function of
>   observations and unobservable parameters such that the function's
>   probability distribution does not depend on the unknown parameters
>   (including nuisance parameters).

Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity

Purely going by this definition, the Z-variable, $$ \frac {\bar{x} - \mu}{\sigma / \sqrt{n}} $$  should be a pivot value, while estimating $ \mu $. Why is it not?

I understand that you can't really use this while calculating a confidence interval because, well, $ \sigma $ is unknown and so you can't calculate a confidence interval.

But what am I missing with the definition?

Comment: The linked Wikipedia page states that $Z$ is indeed a pivotal quantity; why do you think it is not?

Comment: $\bar{X}$ is the *population* mean?   Does your notation above really include $\bar{x}$  (the sample mean, a statistic)?

Comment: @PaulHewson -- Yes, the sample mean.

Comment: @jbowman -- I was taught so! So Z _is_ a pivotal quantity while evaluating mean with unknown variance -- but we just can't use it? Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The difference between a useful and useless pivotal quantity, I suppose, the former of which you get if you use the sample standard deviation instead of the population standard deviation.

Comment: If you don't know $\sigma$, how are you managing to divide by it??